# How to show info in status bar but NOT show it in the notifications in android?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, android-notification-bar

I want to show some info in the android status bar. But I don't want anything to be shown in notifications. But I see an empty place for notification when I drag down status bar and see notification bar. If anyone happen to know how can I get rid of displaying this empty place for notification in the notification bar?

I have read this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html and tryed to create Custom Notification Layout with zero width and height and without notification image and text. But it didn't help. I still see empty area of notification in notification bar.

this is custom notification layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:padding="0dp" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my code inflating notification

```
public class BatteryStatusBarActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final int HELLO_ID = 1;

    //Get a reference to the NotificationManager:
     String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
     NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(ns);

    //Instantiate the Notification:
    int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

    //Define the notification's message and PendingIntent:
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, BatteryStatusBarActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, tickerText, tickerText, contentIntent);
    // redefine content view for notification
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    notification.contentView = contentView;

    //Pass the Notification to the NotificationManager:
    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

    //mNotificationManager.cancel(HELLO_ID);    
}
}
```

Comment: Why would this be good for the user?

Comment: Because he won't see doplicated information.

Comment: Then put *more* information into the notification drawer entry. Your icon for the status bar is tiny, conveying very little information. Use the space in the notification drawer entry to provide more details, or to allow the user to tap on it to bring up an activity to control your application's behavior, etc.

Comment: I think I'll do it if won't find how to do the way I want. But still it is possible - time, battery, signal level which are separated in the right side of status bar are displaying without any notifications.

Comment: Those are not notifications. Those are part of the firmware implementation of the status bar (or system bar on HC/ICS tablets). AFAIK, notifications must have a notification drawer entry. And you cannot create icons in the status bar, other than notifications, except via custom firmware.

Comment: @CommonsWare not the answer I was hoping for on this, d'oh! Thanks a million for taking the time to answer, you've saved me a lot of time trying to figure this out. I was sure I could do this as the Twitter app is able to post text only to the status bar, but I'm guessing it is set up that way in the firmware (since it is built directly into the stock ROM)?

Comment: @RossC: "I was sure I could do this as the Twitter app is able to post text only to the status bar" -- any `Notification` can specify "ticker text". This usually appears in the status bar for just a few seconds before vanishing. It is conceivable that other ROMs do other things with the ticker text.